# New line character in Spring Property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, newline, properties-file

Is there any way to add a new line character to a single Spring property defined in a Eclipse launch configuration? Simply \n does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I want to store a SSH key in a Spring property as showed on the screenshot. After the prefix BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY and before the suffix END RSA PRIVATE KEY there must be a new line.

[image: Eclipse launch configuration editor - Spring Boot properties]

Comment: Do you want to associate one property key with a multiline value?

Comment: @J-Alex Exactly.

Comment: This might be useful as an alternate solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69904488/2200690

Answer (score 0):

Looking at: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445999

It seems it might be possible to use `\\n` to stop eclipse from replacing the character.

Not sure if that's what you're asking? If not, please provide a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve and I'll amend my answer